# Not able to get bluetooth paired android devices name, which is changed programatically from another device

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

I am trying to connect 2 android devices via blue-tooth, I m changing Bluetooth name by bluetoothDevice.setName() method, but the updated name is not showing on another device. The old name is coming, when I click on old name for connecting, connection get to fail and when I again come on the screen, the New name gets reflected.
Please help, trying for a long time.

For getting bonded devices: 
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

```
 if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
  System.out.println("BT not available");
 }
 else {

   if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
       Intent enableAdapter = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
       startActivityForResult(enableAdapter, 0);
   }

   Set<BluetoothDevice> all_devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if (all_devices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice currentDevice : all_devices) {
            log.i("Device Name " + currentDevice.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

For changing name of bluetooth device name:

```
bluetoothDevice.setName()
```

Comment: Share your code, what you are doing?

Comment: Android pair device by MAC, therefore you must did something else wrong